# Why ist UISwitch with letter "I" and "0" for On/Off?

Tags: ios

I made two normal standard UISwitch in a View, it looks very well on mostly Devices, but on a iphone 6 (ios 9.3.3) of my colleague, it shows with letter I and O for On/Off status.

I don't know why and how can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have activated "on off labels" in the accessibility settings on their device. You cannot control this programatically.